# MS access ORDER BY breaking the query (Adodb)

Tags: php, ms-access, adodb

currently I'm working with an access db on php project based on linux environment (unfortunately db type is chosen by client so I can't change it).

I have problem with following query:

```
select DATAORA,PARAMETRO_VALORE,GRANDEZZA from TABLE
where (GRUPPO = 'xxx' and DATAORA > '#2012-01-04 00:00:00#' 
and DATAORA < '#2012-01-05 00:00:00#') 
ORDER BY GRANDEZZA
```

It's working perfectly if I use it without **ORDER BY** clause

```
select DATAORA,PARAMETRO_VALORE,GRANDEZZA from TABLE
where (GRUPPO = 'xxx' and DATAORA > '#2012-01-04 00:00:00#' 
and DATAORA < '#2012-01-05 00:00:00#')
```

But it breaks (0 results, no sign of error) as soon as I add order.

On windows it works perfectly (well after I remove quotes from dates), so I'm really stuck here...

Any suggestion?

Thx.

P.s. (DATAORA = datetie, GRANDEZZA = varchar)

Comment: Strange behavior indeed, have you tried to order with other columns? I don't know PHP, but are you using some library to let your code reach the access db?

Comment: I was wondering too how you're accessing an Access database without Windows.

Comment: I'm using unixodbc as driver for accessing mdb database. Unfortunately it seems that if I add order by clause in any query (even on another table/columns) behavior is the same: query return 0 rows and 0 errors... It's pretty difficult to understand if the problem is environment/db/planet position <.<

For now (since it's for demo) I think that i will be forced to convert mdb access in mysql, and ask my client to export data in sqlite  or something similar